# How can I make sure the program stops running after the IDE has output result

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I have run the code before in NetBeans. However, after I have entered a string and IDE has output the result, I was expecting the program to stop running.

However, there is a bar at the bottom of the NetBeans IDE that indicates the program is still running.

Why is this happening?

What change should I make to my code so that the program will stop running?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Enter a string of characters including punctuation." << endl;
    for (string s; getline(cin, s); cout << endl)
        for (auto i : s)
            if (!ispunct(i)) cout << i;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  The compiler finishes before the program is run.  The compiler doesn't execute your program.

Comment: You have to press Ctrl-D on Linux & Mac OS, or Ctrl-Z on Windows to mark the end of input.

Comment: How did you tell the program that it had reached the end?  Did you consider modifying your code to print a message after the loop is exited?  What about printing each line as it is read?  Basic debugging techniques.  Maybe you only want it to read one string; if so, you don't need the loop to keep on reading more strings.

Answer (score 3):

The program looped back to getline as you told it to with the for statement. Your exit condition is getline returns false. To do this you need to close the file, you do this by entering <kbd>Control-D</kbd> on Unix or <kbd>Control-Z</kbd> on Windows.

Another tactic would be to loop until somebody types 'q' or 'exit' or an empty line.